# MS Teams Personal Tab (Custom App) is not displaying in the side App bar

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have the below queries:

1. We were trying to expose the SharePoint portal in Microsoft Teams by creating a Personal Tabs App. In order to display it in the side app bar, we have added the app in Global Policy (admin.teams->Teams app->setup policy) and rearranged the App to top.

   But the app is not getting displayed in the app bar for any user. Are there any more configurations need to be implemented?
2. Will this take hours to get displayed in the Teams UI, does E3 subscription will take more time to render the APP in Teams compare to E5?
3. If so, how many hours do we need to wait to see the update in Teams UI?

Please note this app is created via App Studio, not custom code.

Reference links:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyB4MBQwICs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies

Comment: It might just be taking a while to take effect. Perhaps give it a few hours.

Comment: Will it take morethan 24 hours in E3 subscription?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I just recall it takes some time. 24 hours is probably a good safe estimate. Is it more than that so far?

Comment: @Nandakumar, Steps provided in youtube link are perfect. Wait for sometime, It should reflect in few hours.

Comment: Yes it is taking 24 hours to get displayed in the side bar. The configured tabs are displaying successfully in Teams web app/via browser. But not rendering in the desktop version. The tabs url changed in the below format to overcome this issue but not sure why this is replicating. 

Tab url format: https://<tenant.sharepoint.com>/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=</sites/lms>/SitePages/Get-started-with-Microsoft-365.aspx

Comment: @Nandakumar, If it is working when you access it from Teams apps collection in the case this should work from pinned apps too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is taking 24 hours to get displayed in the side bar. The configured tabs are displaying successfully in Teams web app/via browser. But not rendering in the desktop version. The tabs url changed in the below format to overcome this issue but not sure why this is replicating. Tab url format: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=/SitePages/Home.aspx